# .htaccess Rewrite rule to strip extension not working?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm don't understand why this isn't working.  It should take any page with .htm extension and strip it.  That will be the page on WordPress site.  But when this runs the .htm stays and get a 404.  What am I missing?

```
RewriteEngine On
# there is an existing rule here that works fine with [R=301,L]
# but the following rule isn't working?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/([^./]+)\.htm$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This one works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Remove `/` after `^`

Comment: As @anubhava states you need to match against _relative_ paths if you implement a `RewriteRule` in a distributed configuration file. The reason is clearly stated in the documentation: "In per-directory context (Directory and .htaccess), the Pattern is matched against only a partial path, for example a request of "/app1/index.html" may result in comparison against "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the RewriteRule is defined."